# if ( isset inside a function for loops

Tags: php

I'm try to write a custom function trying to avoid to rewrite the if(isset everytime I call an array in a loop:

```
function ifvalueexists($valueexists){
if(isset ($valueexists ) ){
    $newvalue = $valueexists;
    return $newvalue;
    }
else {
     $newvalue = '';
     }
     return $newvalue;  
}
```

TEST:

```
$myarray = array(1, 2, 3);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i){
    echo ifvalueexists($myarray[$i]);
}
```

but I still get: Undefined offset: 3  and Undefined offset: 4. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You would not call this function without `$valueexists`, so why check it a second time?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `echo $myarray[$i] ?? '';`?

Comment: you can't test for existence by passing what may not exist into a function and testing it there. by the time isset() is called, you've already tried to access that value just by PASSING IT as the function argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data access is taking place *before* you're calling the function. You are trying to send a non-existent array index as a parameter to the function.  You can get this to work, but you need to pass the entire array as a parameter along with the index you are attempting to access in order to avoid invalid indices, something like this:

```
function ifvalueexists(array $value, $index) {
    if(isset ($value[$index] ) ){
        return $value[$index]; // why not just return the value directly?
    }

    return ''; // no need for else here
}
```

If you wanted to do this in one line, you could do that too:

```
function ifvalueexists(array $value, $index) {
    return isset($value[$index]) ? $value[$index] : '';
}
```

Comment: Since PHP 5.3 (?) you can even use `return isset($value[$index]) ?: ''`

Comment: @watcher Thanks, I tested with `$myarray = array(3, 4, 5);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i){
  echo ifvalueexists($myarray, [$i]);
}` but I get  Illegal offset type in isset or empty Error...

Comment: @codeispoetry thats because your second parameter is now an _array_ itself and not just the index.  call it like this: `ifvalueexists($myarray, $i)`. Array indices cannot be arrays themselves (that's what the error message is telling you)

Comment: thanks! Now I can just call the function when I access array values in loops!!! Fantastic, this will save me a lot of time! Thanks watcher!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be overcomplicating your code. This is just a one liner, rather than the 10+ lines of code you have.

```
$myarray = array(1, 2, 3);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i){
    echo (isset($myarray[$i])) ? $myarray[$i] : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php)**:

```
$myarray = array(1, 2, 3);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i){
   if(array_key_exists($i , $myarray)
      echo $myarray[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Imanali, but Ive many loops and arrays;  I'm trying to put all that in a function and call that function, so I don't need an if everytime I call the arrays in loops

Comment: If you don't want use `array_key_exists` when call function then putt into all functions that you call.